# slide down navbar overlap

Tags: javascript, html

My navigation bar scrolls up and down as it should. My problem area is in the hero section. I have a navigation bar also that does nothing special it goes up with the hero.

I am trying to get the slide down navigation bar to not to conflict with the first navigation bar. Sometimes, when scrolling to the top, the slide navigation bar hasn't gone up yet so there is an overlap.

If you scroll really slow it works fine, but I would like the slide down navigation bar to slide down about half way down the hero section and the same back up.

```js
this.onscroll = function() {
 "use strict";
 scrollNav();
};

function scrollNav() {
 "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250) {        
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-90px";
    }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  position: fixed;
  top: -90px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  display:block;
  transition: top .5s cubic-bezier(.5,.25,.015,1) 0s, opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.5,.25,.015,1) 0s,height .5s cubic-bezier(.5,.25,.015,1) 0s;
 
}

#navbar .header__menu2 {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 90px;
 padding-top: 32px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: "nimbus-sans-condensed" , sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar .header__menu2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
#navbar .header__menu2 a {
 color: #a3a3a3;
 line-height: 24px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar .header__menu2 a:hover {
 color: #e1382c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">hero</div>
<div id="navbar">  
 <div class="header__main2">  
  <nav class="header__menu2">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
  </nav>              
      </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 900px;">section 2</div>
```

Comment: In the provided code the hero's navbar is missing

Comment: right because that nav is not part of the navbar